# Why I got garbage value after reclaring variable in a smaller scope

Tags: c++

```
        int tar = 0;
        {
            int tar = tar;
            cout<<tar;       
        }
```

It prints out 814005873, but what I expected was 0.

Comment: why did you expect `0` ?

Comment: In C++, you can use a variable immediately after it's declared. `int tar` does this (and shadows the outside `tar`) so `int tar = tar` just uses the inside `tar`, which is uninitialized. There's probably a dupe for this somewhere.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Because I assigned a value of 0 to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable in the outer scope is not relevant. You'd get the same with

```
    {
        int tar = tar;
        cout<<tar;       
    }
```

`tar` is not initialzed hence using its value to initialize itself is undefined behavior. All major compilers warn about such case of `tar` being used uninitialized. For example: https://godbolt.org/z/3x437P46K. Don't ignore warnings!

It may look weird that this isnt an error, but for a custom type such initialization can be meaningful. For example:

```
struct foo {
    foo& other;
    foo(foo& other) : other(other) {}
};

int main()
{
    foo f = f;
}
```

`f` holds a reference to itself.

Comment: `void* p = &p;` might be another one.